# Detect the user current location,add a marker onto that position in Sencha Touch V2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sencha-touch-2, dom-events

The code below facilitates a map to be displayed with markers added onto it from data in a JSON file.The getDirections from one marker to another has also been facilitated.

Need to:Detect the user current location,add a marker onto that position and apply that location to the start variable given within the code below so that directions from that current position to the marker that has been tapped can be plotted.

```
Ext.define('Navigator.view.mapcard', {
    extend: 'Ext.Map',
    xtype: 'mapcard',


    config: {
        title: 'Mappa',
        iconCls: 'maps',
       // useCurrentLocation: true,

        mapOptions: {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng('24.859622', '18.84089'),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
            }
        },


        listeners: {
            maprender: function (comp, map) {

                var data = Ext.getStore('Contacts'),
                    marker = [], infowindow = [],
                    dist = [];

                data.on('load', function () {
                    data.each(function (rec, idx, cnt) {
                        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(rec.get('latitude'), rec.get('longitude'));

                        marker[idx] = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: latLng
                        }),
                        infowindow[idx] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: rec.get('title')
                        });


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[idx], 'click', function () {
                            infowindow[idx].open(map, marker[idx]);

                            if (dist.length === 0) {
                                dist.push(rec.get('title'));
                            } else if (dist.length === 1) {
                                dist.push(rec.get('title'));
                            } else if (dist.length > 1) {
                                // need reload map
                                dist = [];
                                dist.push(rec.get('title'));
                            }

                            if (dist.length === 2) {
                                var start = dist[0],
                                    end = dist[1],
                                    request = {
                                        origin: start,
                                        destination: end,
                                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                                    };

                                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
                                    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        //setTimeout(function () { map.panTo(latLng) }, 1000);
                    });
                });


            }
        }

    }
});
```